# Getting error parsing a value to an integer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having this code below

```
int? _trades = data['trades'] ?? 0;
```

so I want to parse data['trades'] to an integer so I did this

```
int? _trades = int.parse(data['trades']) ?? 0;
```

But I got this error:

```
The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed.   Try removing the operator and the right operand.
```

Comment: int.parse() never returns null. see the docs https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/parse.html

Comment: @Omkar76 So it should be like this int? _trades = int.parse(data['trades']) ?

Comment: no. read the error message again. since int.parse() never returns a null there is no point in using a null aware operator. the message tells you to remove operator `??` and right operand `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we use `??` in dart when we expect a `null` value from source and we want to assign a fallback value.

But as mentioned by @omkar76 `int.parse()` does not return the null hence there is no point using `?? 0` at the end because it will never return null instead it will just throw an **error**.

In order to catch the error you can place **try/catch** around the `int.parse()` that way you'll be safely parse the code and your error will get disappear.

Example code

```
void main() {
  var data = {'trades': '2'};//sample data
  int trades = 0; //setting default value
  try {
    int trades = int.parse(data['trades']!);
  } catch (e) {
    print('[Catch] $e');
  }
  print(trades);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int? _trades = data['trades'] ?? 0;

Int? Means the value can be null but you also added ?? Which means if its null then assign 0.

So you can either use

```
int? _trades = data['trades'];
//Or
int _trades = data['trades'] ?? 0;
```